# Adding Slide controls on Libre Office Impress[16.04]

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I'm going on with a project and would like to know how can I add a link to a button so that clicking it would take me to the next slide(Libre office Impress),( simply a button to trigger slides) can someone help? a small picture of the button is given below in the picture(inside the red circle).[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click a graphical object and select the option "Interaction". This will allow you to define, among several other things, an action to move to the next slide when the object is clicked during presentation.

Via the menu, you will reach the option selecting Format - Interaction.

Comment: wow that helped me a lot!!!

Comment: It is a little bit hidden, but once you know ...